# Htmlagilitypack xpath combine contains and not

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to get `tr`, but somehow web developers decided to give the same id, classes to all `tr`, so I have problem to select the specific `tr` that I need. I found only one difference between all `tr` and that is `vAlign='top'` so I need to build XPath that have `id TR_ROW_BANKTABLE`, but dont have `@vAlign='top'`

I tried this but it is not working but I think this is the way, just I don't know the right way to write this.
How to combine `not` and `@id=TR_ROW_BANKTABLE/contains`

```
    //table[@class='arial12NoBold']//tbody//table//tbody//tr[not(@vAlign='top')  
and contains(@id,'TR_ROW_BANKTABLE') ]//td[1]"
```

This is a piece of html code
    Update:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="0" bgcolor="#fefefe">
<tbody>

//This tr that i don't need 

    <tr id="TR_ROW_BANKTABLE" class="TR_ROW_BANKTABLE" align="right" style="display: none;" name="nameTr2">
<td align="center" colspan="7">
<misgeret_table takepartfromcash="ItrotMatach">
<table id="WHITE_BANKTABLE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1" bgcolor="white" bordercolordark="#E2ECF1" bordercolorlight="#2b7cd2" iswhitetable="Y">
<tbody>
<tr class="TR_BANKTABLE" valign="top" align="right">
<td>some text</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
<td>some text</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="white" align="right" style="background-color: white;">
</tbody>
</table>
</misgeret_table>
</td>
</tr>



//This i trying to get

    <tr id="TR_ROW_BANKTABLE" class="TR_ROW_BANKTABLE" bgcolor="#EDF1F4" align="right" onmouseover="printRow(this);" onmouseout="printrowback(this);" style="">
    <td align="right">3.4404000</td>
    <td align="right">60,895.08</td>
    <td align="right">17,700.00</td>
    <td align="right">17,700.00</td>
    <td align="right">02/06/14</td>
    <td align="right">loop</td>
    <td align="right">
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you need such complex expression (behavior of `not` is not always intuitive in XPath) consider using filtering with code instead.

Comment: The way you filter `<tr>` element in XPath looks correct to me. Can you post relevant portion of the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way  i used `onmouseover and onmouseout` and combine them with `and`

```
"//table[@class='arial12NoBold']//tbody//table//tbody//tr[contains(@onmouseout,'printrowback(this);') and  contains(@onmouseover,'printRow(this);') ]//td[1]");
```